# Catch "applied coupon" event to trigger a JS function in Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

In Woocommerce, is there any way trigger JS after applied coupon like this?

I would like to use it in something like this:

```
    $( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
        //do something      
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i got this :)  $( document.body ).on( 'applied_coupon', function(){ });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `applied_coupon` delegated event like in this example that will display an alert box with the applied coupon code *(where the variable `coupon` is the applied coupon code)*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $( "body" ).on( 'applied_coupon', function(event, coupon){
        // Example: Displaying an alert message with the applied coupon code
        alert('Applied coupon code: "' + coupon + '"\n' + 'Event type: "' + event.type + '"');
    });
});
</script>
```

Tested and works.

Comment: +1 for @LoicTheAztec's answer. Just for those who would like to use this at the checkout, the trigger is applied_coupon_in_checkout.